# Spring - access @Autowired service from AbstractMessageHandler

Tags: spring, service, autowired

I have a SpringBootApplication which subscribes to MQTT broker. MQTT messages need to be saved to Database, but I cannot access my @Autowired service.

Exception I get:

> *Field deviceService in com.example.MqttMessageHandler required a bean of type 'com.example.service.DeviceService' that could not be found.*

MQTTApiApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "{com.example}")
public class MQTTApiApplication { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder(MQTTApiApplication.class)
                .web(false).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {    
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
                .handle(new MqttMessageHandler())
                .get();
    }
}
```

MqttMessageHandler.java

```
public class MqttMessageHandler extends AbstractMessageHandler {

    @Autowired
    DeviceService deviceService;

    @Override
    protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        deviceService.saveDevice(new Device());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MQTTApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MQTTApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttinFlow(MqttMessageHandler handler) {
        return IntegrationFlows
        .from(mqttInbound())
        .handle(handler).get();
    }
}
```

MqqtMessageHandler.java

```
@Component
public class MqttMessageHandler extends AbstractMessageHandler{

    @Autowired
    private DeviceService deviceService;

    @Override
    protected void handleMessageInternal(String message) {
        //...
    }

}
```

DeviceService.java

```
@Service
public class DeviceService {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceRepository repository;

    //...
}
```

DeviceController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DeviceController {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlow flow;

    //...
}
```

DeviceRepository.java

```
@Repository
public class DeviceRepository {
    public void save() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've added @Component annotation, but still get the same error. I'm accessing the service from RestController normally.

Comment: And what about DeviceService?

Comment: When I put DeviceService into RestController, I'm able to access the DeviceService (which is Autowired).
The problem is that I cannot access Autowired Services/Controllers from MqttMessageHandler.

Comment: MqttMessageHandler is in the same packages as your service?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same package

Comment: Try to change your IntegrationFlow bean to:  
`@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow(MqttMessageHandler messageHandler) {    
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
.handle(messageHandler)
.get();
    }`

Comment: Parameter 0 of method mqttInFlow in com.example.MQTTApiApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.service.MqttMessageHandler' that could not be found.

Comment: oh, I forgot to say... try to remove scanBasePackages from your @SpringBootApplication

Comment: when I removed 'scanBasePackages' I got new error: Now it does not find the bean for DeviceRepository, which is Autowired in DeviceService

Comment: I edited the answer with a test I did here, it worked normally

Comment: :( no problem!!